# Process Builder - scheduled action problem

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, scheduled

We have found out a big problem by using Scheduled Action in a process builder.

In a process builder we have built a condition that fires when record is in a given status and this condition starts a scheduled action.

By monitoring Paused and Waiting Interviews and all record in this given status, sometimes (sporadically) we noticed that the number of waiting interviews doesn't match with the number of record in that status.

I went over a lot of post around forums in Internet and it's a common problem, sometimes meaningless the flow scheduled action doesn't fire.

Someone has found a workaround to this problem?

Thanks in advance.
Fabio

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the conditions of your process builder were already met before activating it.

It's impossible for us to help you without you sharing with us the exact details of the process builder. It won't be a bug in process builder it will be some small gap in the logic.

Please post screenshots of all of the parts of the process.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I thought it might be as you wrote but the problem is that the process builder fires when an update occurs and it happens rarely in our system, with other record that comes from the same process it doesn't happen. It seems that process builder is not triggered even though records has got all the conditions for trigger the process.

Comment: You will still need to attach screen shots of your process of you want help